# @IBInspectableを使うとき「getとsetのペア」もしくは「didSetのみ」など使い分けがあるようだが、違いがわからない

Tags: swift, xcode

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35372610/1979953
では下記のように `set`と `get`のペア。

```
@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor? {
    set {
        layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
    get {
        guard let color = layer.borderColor else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIColor(cgColor: color)
    }
}
```

https://qiita.com/touyu/items/92293c5f9448bdbfa384
では

```
@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius
        self.clipsToBounds = (self.cornerRadius > 0)
    }
}
```

というように `didSet` のみとなっています。

どういう意図で使い分けるものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

厳密ではない点、ご容赦願います。

上の例は、コンピューテッドプロパティ（計算によって値が求まるプロパティ）で、`UIColor`クラスのインスタンスを返しますが、直接`UIColor`のインスタンスを保存しているわけではなく、（対象の？）レイヤーにボーダーカラーを`CGColor`クラスのインスタンス（なプロパティ）としてセットすることで、あたかも、`UIColor`が保存され、レイヤーの枠の色が変更されます。
同様に、現在のレイヤーの枠の色を取得するのも、値をストアした（メンバー）がないので、変数をそのまま返せません。このため、レイヤーのボーダーカラーを取得し、設定されていなければ`nil`を、設定されていれば、`UIColor`クラスのインスタンスにキャストして`. borderColor`で取得出来るようにするためにはどうすれば良いか？を定義したものが、`get {}`の内容になります。

対して下の例は、副作用のあるストアードプロパティ（値を直接保持しておくプロパティ）です。
`cornerRadius`なので、角の丸み具合の値を`cornerRadius`という`CGFloat`型のメンバー変数に代入して覚えておきますが、`cornerRadius`がインスタンスの外部からセットされたとき**のみ**、その数値を代入して保存するだけでなく、自身の持つレイヤーの`cornerRadius`プロパティにその値を代入することで、レイヤーの角の丸さをセットされたときの**副作用**として変更する動作を行うので、`didset {}`が必要ですが、角の丸み具合は、メンバーで持っているので、`get`はその値をそのまま返すだけで良いので、`get {}`を省略しているのです。